# multiple permission request order

Tags: android, android-permissions

In my app there are 4 permissions. They are

```
   String[] permissions= new String[]{ Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG, 
            Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, 
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE};
```

If i run app in android emulator order of asking permission in the above array order.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

But running app phone it first asks Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS then others.  Is any order for asking permission in android?

Comment: Why would you need the permissions to be requested in order? If you don't have a permission for something, you can ask before attempting the operation. Order should not matter.

Comment: Mine is tabbed app, so i can load data into each tab in the order of permission asked

Comment: may be Protection level: dangerous of READ_CONTACTS that's why they asking first

Comment: after read contacts ask for Read phone state may be

Comment: Can you show your Manifest please?

Comment: Yes i think it is in order of manifest file.  Why emulator asks right

Comment: I changed the order of permission in manifest file.  Now it works as correct order.  Thank you

Comment: It's relates to your task order. If you first want to do read contacts, it asks first. But as i know you need to set permission request messages when running application. Then permission order will base on the requestpernission what u triggered